# cannot import name '_jsonl' from partially initialized module 'jsonl'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jsonlines

I am trying to install the python jsonl module on an Ubuntu system.  Tried on two different computers and get the same exact error:

**pip install jsonl**

```
Collecting jsonl
  Downloading jsonl-1.6.tar.gz (9.0 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5lw5f9ew/jsonl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5lw5f9ew/jsonl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-5lw5f9ew/jsonl/pip-egg-info         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5lw5f9ew/jsonl/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-5lw5f9ew/jsonl/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import jsonl
      File "/tmp/pip-install-5lw5f9ew/jsonl/jsonl/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        from jsonl import _jsonl as jsonl
    ImportError: cannot import name '_jsonl' from partially initialized module 'jsonl' (most likely due to a circular import) (/tmp/pip-install-5lw5f9ew/jsonl/jsonl/__init__.py)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any ides on how to fix this?  As the same exact error occurs on two systems, I'm thinking it's a config error on my part, but no idea on how to resolve.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`jsonl`, the latest version [1.6](https://pypi.org/project/jsonl/1.6/) was  released in 2014. I can install it with Python 2.7 but not with Python 3. The bottom line: it's an outdated abandoned project, forget it.

Another problem: it requires `simplejson` but doesn't declare it as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Didn't really want to use python anyway.   Learning how to work with OpenAI API and most of the examples use python.   Decided to just move forward using php instead.